# Use SFINAE but don't create a compile error

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

My program generates random strings that have a "type" and an identifier. Like so:

```
float       lHTY8Au8b9 = float();
int         dO3PNUInH6 = int();
float       B_MtShimak = float();
float       hgi_TzaVEv = float();
double      mfW8kr6h6q = double();
std::string lSLj9antfj = std::string();
char        MQkeARWYTL = char();
char        Oe7G_ZRJy6 = char();
float       qUwmOWeilK = float();
double      FJYIODwQfx = double();
```

Then I have the following to see if two arbitrary variables can be added:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<A, B>::value, decltype(A() + B())>::type
    try_to_add(A a, B b) {
        return a + b;
    }
```

Of course, it works because I get the following error:

```
main.cpp:51:54: error: no matching function for call to ‘try_to_add(double&, std::string&)’

  try_to_add<double,std::string>(mfW8kr6h6q,lSLj9antfj);
```

However what I want instead is a list of candidates that don't cause a compile error. I can't hardcode the template parameters because it only accepts ints, and I cannot check inside the generator program because they're just strings, and attempting to use `try_to_add` with non-convertible types will cause a compile error. I know that SFINAE is the wrong approach, but is there a way to get `try_to_add` to simply do nothing, rather than generate a compile error?

[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2735d5e1af454942)

Comment: `is_convertible` looks weirdly asymmetric. Why not just use `std::common_type`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I did whatever came to mind first. Thanks for the fast answer, and I'll do more research.

Comment: how do you get the result value when `try_to_add` does nothing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add another overlaod with the inverse condition that does nothing.

```
template <typename A, typename B>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<A, B>::value>::type
try_to_add(A, B) { }
```

Comment: +1 This needs a return value of some sort, doesn't it? (and I *think* that somewhat points to a flaw in the do-nothing approach the OP thinks  of as a solution).

Comment: There a times I seriously wish I has such harmony with the language as you and a few others on this site do (Johannes would be another glittering example), and this is one of them, because I just can't see it. (I did just wake up about 20 minutes ago, so I have an excuse, albeit a pitiful one). Sorry if it is something obvious.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Hah, thanks, I'm not sure if "harmony" can ever be used in the context of C++ :-) What I mean is that the second parameter of `enable_if` is defaulted to `void`, so the above function has return type `void`. The OP is welcome to change that to something meaningful, based on how this is going to be used.

Comment: Duh. My god I need to make some coffee. Thanks for pointing me at the tree in my forest =P As many times as I use enable-if, I'm a pure dolt for not seeing that. Again, thanks, sir.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a few useful techniques.  First, instead of `is_convertible`, we just try adding.  if it works, bonus.  Second, I use perfect forwarding.

Finally, I use a variardic pack for the "does work" catch-all.  This is the `sink` technique.

```
#include <iostream>

#define RETURNS(X) ->decltype(X) { return (X); }

template<typename A, typename B>
auto try_to_add(A&& a, B&& b)
  RETURNS( std::forward<A>(a) + std::forward<B>(b) )

template<typename... Ts>
void try_to_add( Ts&&... ) {
  std::cout  << "failed to add\n";
}

struct foo {};

int main() {
  int a =1, b=2;
  std::cout << try_to_add( a, b ) << "\n";
  try_to_add( a, foo{} );
}
```

The `RETURNS` macro works around the lack of automatic return type deduction in C++11.  In C++1y we will have a better option that lets us omit the repeated `-> (X) { returns (X); }` annoyance.

The point of the variardic args is that such a pack will only match if all overloads without the variardic args fail to match (they are considered last).  This is useful because you don't have to maintain the `bool` condition in two different spots at once (once inverted).

The `RETURNS` macro can be expanded:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
auto try_to_add(A&& a, B&& b)
-> decltype( std::forward<A>(a) + std::forward<B>(b) )
  { return ( std::forward<A>(a) + std::forward<B>(b) ); }
```

if you prefer not to use macros (which is understandable).

Comment: What's with the naked `auto` in the second overload? The problem is what do you return when there's nothing you can return?

Comment: @KerrekSB typo, but one that gcc didn't mind.  Maybe because it has some C++1y features and determined the return type was `void`?  Not sure.

Comment: Yes, that's plausible. The return value may be deduced even from complex function bodies in C++14.